# How to handle load balancing with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm proposing my company start using Azure Web Apps for our Web App. Others would like to set up Azure Virtual Machines to run the web app, only the web app.

The reason they would like to do that is because of the way they currently handle roll outs. **I would like to find documentation on how this is handled with Azure Web Apps.**

Currently we have 2 servers that are load balanced. When it's time for a deployment, we bring down one server, updated it, then switch to that server, bringing down the 2nd server to update that.

**I'm sure there's a better way to do that using Web Apps.** I'm not completely familiar with the server end yet, but am trying to get information.

What we want to avoid is the user getting 30-60 seconds of load time if we publish a change.

Answer (score 2):

Web Apps provide multiple deployment slots, specifically to allow for multiple deployed versions (e.g. production, dev, test).

Also built-in is the ability to swap slots. This allows you to deploy a new build to a testing slot, test it, then swap with the production slot. At that point, your end users start working with the new app version. Your previous version is in the other slot (until you tear it down).

More information on Web App deployment slots [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/).